# Correct way to link href to jQuery UI tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

What is the correct way to link a href to a jQuery UI tab?

I've tried this so far and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    $("#search").tabs();

    $('#2a').click(function () {
        $("#search").tabs('select', 1);
        return false;
    });

    $('#2b').click(function () {
        $("#search").tabs('select', 2);
        return false;
    });
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/bWHt6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you do it, except that indexes start from zero. The first tab is `0`, the second is `1` and so on.

```
$('#2a').click(function () {
    $("#search").tabs('select', 0);
    return false;
});

$('#2b').click(function () {
    $("#search").tabs('select', 1);
    return false;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bWHt6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search").tabs();

        $('#2a').click(function () {
            $("#search").tabs('select', 0);
            return false;
        });

        $('#2b').click(function () {
            $("#search").tabs('select', 1);
            return false;
        });
})  ;
```

Check Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bWHt6/3/